# Django1.9 AttributeError at /books/ type object 'Books' has no attribute 'Objects'

Tags: python, django

I am beginner and I am trying to fetch data from db . But I don't know why I am getting this error and completely stuck here. I am following video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_cPM7CgG-Fc .

**Error:**

```
AttributeError at /books/
type object 'Books' has no attribute 'Objects'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/books/
Django Version: 1.9
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
type object 'Books' has no attribute 'Objects'
Exception Location: F:\FYP\db2\testproject\books\views.py in index, line 7
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.8
Python Path:    
['F:\\FYP\\db2\\testproject',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-7.0-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\networkx-1.9.1-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\decorator-3.4.0-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\sys-1.0-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\requests-2.5.1-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\beautifulsoup-3.2.1-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\beautifulsoup4-4.3.2-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\nltk-3.0.1-py2.7-win32.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\lxml-3.4.1-py2.7-win32.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\stripogram-1.5-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\html2text-2014.12.29-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\dom-0.6-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\termcolor-1.1.0-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\simplejson-3.6.5-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\xmltodict-0.9.2-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\mysql-0.0.1-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\mysql_python-1.2.5-py2.7-win32.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\textstat-0.1.6-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\utils-0.7-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\tweetpy-0.1-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\requests_oauthlib-0.5.0-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\oauthlib-0.7.2-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\tweepy-3.3.0-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\six-1.9.0-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\cython-0.22-py2.7-win32.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy-1.9.2-py2.7-win32.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pytz-2015.4-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\python_dateutil-2.4.2-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas-0.16.1-py2.7-win32.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-7.0.3-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib-1.4.3-py2.7-win32.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pyparsing-2.0.3-py2.7-win32.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\html5lib-1.0b8-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pelican-3.6.3-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\unidecode-0.04.19-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\blinker-1.4-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\docutils-0.12-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pygments-2.1-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\jinja2-2.8-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\feedgenerator-1.7-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win32.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\mechanize-0.2.5-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Windows\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Python27',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 29 Apr 2016 11:26:32 +0000
```

files from **books** directory:

model.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Books(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    read = models.CharField(max_length=3)

    def _unicode_(self):
        return self.title + "/"+ self.author+ "/" + self.read
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from books.models import Books

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    list =  Books.Objects.all()
    return HttpResponse(list)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.index),

]
```

from root:
urls.py

```
"""testproject URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Add an import:  from blog import urls as blog_urls
    2. Import the include() function: from django.conf.urls import url, include
    3. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^blog/', include(blog_urls))
"""
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^books/', include('books.urls')),
]
```

Comment: `objects`, not `Objects`!

Comment: In `views.py` change `list =  Books.Objects.all()` to `list =  Books.objects.all().`

Comment: thanks guys. I spend whole day. but i am not getting real results but only getting Books objectBooks ...   
after doing so. Any idea?

Comment: Also - for goodness sake don't name your list `list`.

Comment: I suggest you follow the tutorial all the way through. And as @IntrepidBrit said, be careful with naming variables, don't use python reserved keywords.

Comment: You need **double** underscores in your unicode method: `def __unicode__(self):`

Comment: ok. Tell me one thing guys does literals does not work (as i ve written self.title + "/"+ self.author+ "/" + self.read ) in webpage? here. bcz i m getting string "/" along with data.

Comment: If you use a backslash, you will have better success (with respect to string literals only. It'll likely break somewhere else)

Comment: but 1 thing made me more stranger. Like i opened django admin and in it
Home › Books › Bookss and in Bookss my data are label as:
Twuilight/Book/author

Comment: now whats that i ve seen such thing in Mysql. Any idea?

Comment: Unfortunately @user3508182, Stack Overflow is a Q&A site which focusses with dealing with a specific question and getting it answered. What it's not good for is a "stream of improvements/problem solving" like this is developing into.

Comment: My advice would be to tie off this question, marking the answer from @onkar as accepted and then starting a new question.

Comment: ok i shall be posting on other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change

```
def index(request):
    booklist =  Books.objects.all() #Objects changed to objects ; 
    return HttpResponse(booklist)
```